# Encountering Internal Server Error - How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue in my web application?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask-sqlalchemy, http-delete

App.jsx:39 Error deleting restaurant. Server returned 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

I am building a React application that uses the Flask backend API, when i try deleting from the front end it keeps telling me Internal Server Error, i have tried fixing the issue but it keeps persisting.This is how i have written the code for delete in my backend:

```
def delete(self, restaurant_id):
        restaurant = Restaurant.query.get(restaurant_id)
        if restaurant:
            db.session.delete(restaurant)
            db.session.commit()
            return '', 204
        else:
            abort(404, error='Restaurant not found')

api.add_resource(RestaurantResource, '/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>')
```

And this is how the front end codes looks like:

```
const handleDeleteRestaurant = (restaurantId) => {
    // Delete the selected restaurant
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/restaurants/${restaurantId}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          // Refresh the list of restaurants after deletion
          fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/restaurants')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setRestaurants(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching restaurants after deletion:', error));
        } else {
          console.error(`Error deleting restaurant. Server returned ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error deleting restaurant:', error));
  };
```

Comment: Flask should record the error traceback in its log. This would be in the terminal that flask is running in if you are using the dev server,  Find the traceback and [edit] it into your question so that we can see what is going wrong.